# Header out of line

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a link, and it is below my header. I have tried float:top (I don't even think that is real)

```css
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0%
}

#links {
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <header>
    <h1>Jackson Pope</h1>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What is this **supposed** to look like?

Comment: I want the "About me" text to align with the Jackson Pope text, sorry for not clarifying earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
header {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#links {
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <h1>Jackson Pope</h1>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to have the link still pinned at the top, then use `position: fixed;`

```css
.header {
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 1%;
  margin: 0%
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#links {
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-align: right;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <header>
    <h1>Jackson Pope</h1>
    <div id="links">
      <a href="about.html">About Me</a>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

Comment: But how would I then align it with the "Jackson Pope" text.
Thanks,
Jackson Pope